# illegal reference to non-static member 'Sun::m_SunTexture'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am not overly competent in C++ and this compiler error is just making no sense to me.  The following line calls the compiler error shown in the title:

```
m_SunTexture = LudoTextureManager::GetInstance()->GetTextureData(hardcoded.c_str()).m_Texture;
```

where m_SunTexture is defined in my header file as

```
IDirect3DTexture9 *m_SunTexture;
```

in the private section of my header file.  Why is this!  This makes no sense to me.

Here is more code, as requested.   m_SunTexture is being called in this function

```
void Sun::DrawSun()
{
    std::wstring hardcoded = L"..\\Data\\sun.jpg";
    m_SunTexture = LudoTextureManager::GetInstance()->GetTextureData(hardcoded.c_str()).m_Texture;
    //more code here, cut off because it's useless for this.
}
```

DrawSun is defined in the header file as:

```
static void DrawSun();
```

under the public section of my header file.

Comment: This needs more code to make sense.

Comment: Really?  I'll try adding some more that might be useful..but I can't see how any other code would be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that the first line of code is in a static function, which is referring to the non-static member "m_SunTexture".

See [this](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/c-plus-plus/c-plus-plus-static-functions.html) for more information. Essentially, static functions don't have a "this" pointer, so referring to non-static members (which belong to each instance of the class) doesn't make any sense.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense actually.  I'm not sure why this funciton was static in the first place.  Thank you!

Comment: No probs, thanks for updating the question with the function declaration :-)